# How to access/(read files from) /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc.appName folderpath in Android 11?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to access **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc.appName** folderpath?
When I am trying to access in that way:

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data";
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

It is not returning anything, which means the **files** is null.

Comment: If your app is `com.abc.appName`, then use `getExternalFilesDir()` to access your app's portion of external storage. If your app is not `com.abc.appName`, then you do not have access to this location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can use

`context.getExternalFilesDir(String type)`

where type parameter refers to the type of file e.g.  `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` or `Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC`, etc...

if you would like to access the folder itself, just pass null to `getExternalFilesDir` method.

```
val folder = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)
val files = folder?.listFiles()
Log.d("Your Tag", "onCreate: ${folder?.path}")
Log.d("Your Tag", "onCreate: Your files are ${files}")
```

this will return the path as:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/*yourPackageName*/files

Your files are ....
```

Comment: But I want to access the Android folder, which is not available that way.

Comment: I updated the answer to be abl to access the folder itself. 
Hope it helps.